# Laravel Select2 Box not filtering

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

in my Laravel 5.4 app I want to use Select2 to filter for my "Providers" like that:

https://paste.laravel.io/RowKK

The Select2 Box show the correct content but when I start typing the name of a Provider it doesn't filter the correct items.

When using the same on the example pages, this is working.

Any ideas what I make wrong?

Regards

kay899

Comment: you should be passing your term for filtering. read more about select2 https://select2.github.io/options.html#results

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will still be your API backend that will do the filtering, all you have to do is to pass the query term via `data` property in your ajax. Example the `params.term` was passed to a `q` property and pulled from the API backend.

**Example GitHub Repositories pulling:**

```js
function formatRepo (repo) {
  if (repo.loading) return repo.text;
  return repo.full_name
}

function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
  return repo.full_name || repo.text;
}

$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
  placeholder: 'Select an item',
  ajax: {
    url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            page: params.page
          };
        },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
            // notice we return the value of more so Select2 knows if more results can be loaded
          //console.log(data.items)
          params.page = params.page || 1;
          return {
            results: data.items,
            pagination: {
              more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
            }
          };
        },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  templateResult: formatRepo,
  templateSelection: formatRepoSelection

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="js-data-example-ajax" style="width:500px;">
  <option selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```